# Is $\mathbb{P}^n(\mathbb{Q})$ a manifold?

Tags: number-theory, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Is $\mathbb{P}^n(\mathbb{Q})$ a (smooth) manifold? I think it is a real differentiable manifold, but what is its dimension? 0? Must the topology on $\mathbb{Q}$ as a topological manifold, be the discrete topology? What is the (real) dimension of $\mathbb{Q}$? Of $\mathbb{P}^n(\mathbb{Q})$? Or, must we only speak of $\mathbb{Q}$-dimension? Do features of $\mathbb{Q}\subset\mathbb{R}$ carry over to $\mathbb{P}^n(\mathbb{Q})\subset\mathbb{R}$, such as:

- Does $\mathbb{P}^n(\mathbb{Q})$ have `measure zero' in $\mathbb{P}^n(\mathbb{R})$ (is there an appropriate measure here?)? (Does there exist $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\mathbb{P}^n(Q)$ has positive volume?)
- Is $\mathbb{P}^n(\mathbb{Q})$ still dense in $\mathbb{P}^n(\mathbb{R})$?
- Does $T\mathbb{Q}^n$ have $\mathbb{Q}$-dimension 2n, and real dimension 0?
- Is $\mathbb{P}^n(\mathbb{Q})$ orientable for $n$ odd?
- Is $\mathbb{P}^n(\mathbb{Q})$ homeomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{Q})$?

(This is a stretch, if the others haven't been): Can viewing $\mathbb{P}^n(\mathbb{Q})$ as a manifold answer any (admittedly, elementary) questions in number theory?

Any books or references on this subject would be much appreciated, if they exist. Thanks!

Comment: A manifold must be locally isomorphic to $\Bbb{R}^k$, so $\Bbb{P^n(Q)}$ is not. You can try to generalize manifolds to other fields (mainly $\Bbb{Q}_p$) it has interesting applications in $p$-adic analysis, no idea if it works with $\Bbb{Q}$. The idea that $\Bbb{Q/ Z}$ and $\Bbb{Q^*/ 2^Z}$ are $\Bbb{Q}$-manifolds doesn't seem crazy.

Comment: One issue I see with giving $\Bbb Q^n$ as a local model for a topology is that all $\Bbb Q^n$ are homeomorphic for $n>0$.

Comment: @reuns does the discrete topology on $\mathbb{P}^n(\mathbb{Q})$ allow us to say locally isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^0$?

Comment: @Gae. S. I've seen that, too, that's why I ask whether $\mathbb{P}^n(\mathbb{Q})$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{Q})$. I guess I'm not sure what to make of `$\mathbb{Q}$'-dimension. If we talk about locally diffeomorphic, then I guess I don't have a good notion of $\mathbb{Q}$-dimension.

Comment: What works is to start with a metric space embedded into its completion, the real dimension of the completion of (the metric space) $\Bbb{Q}^n$ is $n$, on the completions we can use the ($C^1$ ?) real manifold definitions and check if the maps restrict to the "$\Bbb{Q}$-manifold". @Gae.S. is saying that a broader approach has good chance to fail

Comment: @ReginaldAnderson Yes, $\Bbb P^1(\Bbb Q)$ and $\Bbb P^n(\Bbb Q)$ are homeomorphic, because all countable metric spaces without isolated points are.

Comment: [This MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/207205/differential-topology-over-mathbbq) shows how a naive extension of the concept of differentiable manifold runs into a similar trivilisation of the geometry.

Comment: @Gae.S. yes, I've seen that. Thanks

Comment: @reuns so your final answer is that $\mathbb{Q}^n$ and $\mathbb{P}^n(\mathbb{Q})$ cannot be viewed as zero-dimensional real manifolds, using the discrete topology? I still think they're Hausdorff, second-countable, and locally diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^0$.

Comment: I think I want to call all countable point sets 0-dimensional smooth real manifolds, and I don't think anyone can stop me!

Comment: Sure if you give them the discrete topology, they are 0-dimensional manifolds, but then calling them $\Bbb{Q}$ or $\Bbb{P}^n\Bbb{Q}$ is very misleading. Instead, it would be preferable to call them $\Bbb{N}$ or $\Bbb{Z}$, since these are countable sets whose natural topology is the discrete topology.

Comment: @jgon That's really interesting. Thank you.

Comment: One should treat them not as manifolds but as sets of ${\mathbb Q}$-points of varieties (schemes). This viewpoint is indeed quite useful for number-theoretic purposes and there is an area of mathematics, called, [arithmetic algebraic geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_geometry), built around varieties/schemes defined over rational numbers. The notion of a homeomorphism is inappropriate in this setting, the right concepts are biregular and birational maps. There are still (Zariski) tangent spaces, etc.

Comment: @Moishe Kohan Would you view $\mathbb{P}^n(\mathbb{Q})$ as $\mathbb{Q}$-points of $\mathbb{P}^n(\mathbb{C})$ if you were given, say, a Diophantine equation (what would you call the relevant `ambient scheme' here)? I (think I) understand enough to know that, say smooth 2n-dimensional real quadrics are birational to $\mathbb{P}^n(\mathbb{C})$ (and to $\mathbb{A}^n(\mathbb{C})$?) via stereographic projection, and that birationality is too coarse to detect mirror symmetry. I guess the less-convoluted statement is that smooth quadric hypersurfaces of $\mathbb{P}^n(\mathbb{C})$ are rational

Comment: @Moishe Kohan my question was basically though: Does one stand to gain anything by viewing projective spaces over $\mathbb{Q}$ as a manifold, even if that's not something traditionally done. I've attended conferences (albeit online) in arithmetic geometry lol I've heard the phrase before, thanks.

Comment: The right language is to view $P^n({\mathbb Q})$ as the set of rational point of $P^n$ where $P^n$ is viewed as a scheme. (Schemes can be understood as certain functors from commutative rings to sets.) In the realm of algebraic geometry, "manifolds" are still very important, they are "nonsingular/smooth schemes."

Comment: $\mathbb{P}^n$ of what? Yes, we've all read Hartshorne

Comment: @ReginaldAnderson: $P^n$ is the functor which sends each commutative ring $R$ to $P^n(R)= P(R^{n+1})$. Here, if $M$ is a projective $R$-module, then $P(M)$ is the set of projective rank 1 submodules $V\subset M$ such that $M/V$ is projective.

Comment: Okay @Moise Kohan please forgive me, I have not stated my question very well. Suppose someone gave us a better thought up Diophantine equation than x^4 + 10xy^3 - z^4 = 10. Could the word `manifold' ever appear in an answer as to whether or not that equation had solutions in $\mathbb{Z}^3$